# Django validation errors not being displayed on webpage but are being read and shown within console

Tags: python, django

I am creating a user signup page for my website and I am trying to make custom validation fields for my form.  I am trying to get the validation errors to be shown on the webpage but I cannot seem to get them to display. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the HTML part but I am new to this and am not sure. Below are the setup of my files

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class createUser(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='username',
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        required=True
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='password',
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        required=True
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='password2',
        max_length=30,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        required=True
    )
    email = forms.CharField(
        label='email',
        max_length=50,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        required=True
    )
    canvas_token = forms.CharField(
        label='token',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "input"}),
        required=True
    )
        
    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        if not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("This password does not contain an uppercase character")

        return password
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Auth(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    email_address = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    canvas_token = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        # this will name the object entry within the database to the username that was entered
        return self.username
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import createUser
from .models import Auth
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


# Create your views here.
def login_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "login.html", {})
    # Show the login page (username, password)


def account_setup(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # check if the request is post
    form = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = createUser(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # if the form is valid, the user data will be saved and the user will be redirected back to the login page
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            password2 = request.POST['password2']
            email = request.POST['email']

            instance = Auth(username=username, email_address=email, password=password)
            instance.save()
            print("data has been saved to DB")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            # if the form is not valid the user will be redirected to the same page but the validation errors will be displayed
            form = createUser()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "accountSetup.html", context)
```

html page being displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Cheat Checker</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'login_page/images/icons/favicon.ico' %}"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/vendor/animate/animate.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/css/util.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_page/css/main.css' %}">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('../static/login_page/images/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST"> {%csrf_token %}
                    <span class="login100-form-logo">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                    </span>

                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                        Create Account
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="logininput100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required minlength="6">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input class="logininput100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required minlength="8">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Re-enter password">
                        <input class="logininput100" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password" required minlength="8">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter Email">
                        <input class="logininput100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter Canvas Token">
                        <input class="logininput100" type="text" name="canvas_token" placeholder="Canvas Token">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                            Create Account
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-10">
                        <p class="create_account">
                            Already have an account?
                        <a class="create_account" href="{% url 'login' %}">
                            Click here to login
                        </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

console output to show that the error is being read but not displayed

[07/Jan/2023 16:35:49] "GET /accountSetup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3906
This password does not contain an uppercase character
password123
[07/Jan/2023 16:36:08] "POST /accountSetup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3906

I am not sure why this is being shown on the get response instead of the post :(

Comment: Remove this `form = createUser()` in the else it should work.

Comment: The `form = createUser()` should be in the `else` block of `if request.method == 'POST':` and not in the `else` block of `if form.is_valid():`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show forms on your template like this:

```
{{ form }}
```

and for errors you can add this code to your template:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

or

```
{{ form.password.errors }}
```

I suggest you read the document [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/) first before doing all these things.

I hope it helps.